# Ubuntu LDAP auth - offline cache / network init speed

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ldap, authentication, ubuntu-12.04

I have configured LDAP auth for Ubuntu using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication).

The authentication works, but I have connection problems after reboot & suspend.
Although the PC is configured using a static ip, after the login screen has been loaded, the pc needs still 10-15 seconds for the network-interface to be up & running. So when I enter my username & password immediately after booting, the login screen hangs and prompts a message `Invalid user/pw`.

So is there a simple solution for configuring ldap-auth to use a local cache when the server is not available? Or is there a possibility to speedup the network initialization?

**Edit**

After adding a static configuration to `/etc/network/interfaces`, I have a running network-connection on the login-screen, but unfortunately the booting takes now 10-15 seconds (Boot-Splash-Text: "Waiting for Network Connection")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a offline credential cache in sssd that you can configure for your purpose but you probably need at least one successful online credential verification.  Check the  `sssd.conf(5)` man page for details and read about `offline_credentials_expiration` and the related stanzas.

This only solves the part of the question what to do if the authentication source is not available - for the boot process itself you would simply need to wait the 15 seconds.

You could try to minimize the 15 seconds somehow by reordering of the boot sequence.